# Difference of two int pointer that is greater than INT_MAX

Tags: c

Is is possible that the difference of two `int*` pointers to elements of the same array is greater than `INT_MAX`?

If so how could I access the elements of such an array that are beyond `INT_MAX`?

Comment: The same way the difference between two `char` elements of a `char` array can be greater than `CHAR_MAX`.

Comment: Pointers are not integers, `INT_MAX` is not related to pointers.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite I know that pointers are not integers but their difference can be interpreted as an integer.

Comment: But not as an `int` (at least that's not guaranteed). Learning C from obscure YT videos or online tutorials is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is is possible that the difference of two `int*` pointers on the elements of the same array is greater than `INT_MAX`?

Yes this is possible.  An array can be larger that `INT_MAX` elements.  Such large *arrays* are infrequently  used.

C provides `ptrdiff_t` as the integer type for pointer subtraction.

```
int *pointer_a;
int *pointer_b;
...
// pointer_a, pointer_b point to elements in the same array object.
ptrdiff_t diff = pointer_a - pointer_b;

// Use `%td` to print a `ptrdiff_t`.
printf("diff %td\n", diff);
```

> When two pointers are subtracted, both shall point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object; the result is the difference of the subscripts of the two array elements. The size of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (a signed integer type) is `ptrdiff_t` defined in the `<stddef.h>` ... C11dr §6.5.6 9

---

> how could I access the elements of such an array that are beyond `INT_MAX`?

To index elements outside the `int` range, use a type that is specified to work.

`size_t` is some *unsigned* type specified to be wide enough to index all the array.

```
// some big array, maybe in global memory.
int big[10000000000];

....
size_t index = foo();
printf("big[%zu] = %d\n", index, big[index]);
```

Comment: `ptrdiff_t` just kicks the can down the street. The C standard does not guarantee that `ptrdiff_t` is large enough to hold the result of an otherwise valid subtraction of two pointers. C 2018 6.5.6 9 admits the possibility it is insufficient, and J.2 notes that undefined behavior may result. I also do not see that it guarantees that `size_t` is wide enough to index any array.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OP ask about possibilities.  Pointer subtraction is specified as returning type `ptrdiff_t`. `ptrdiff_t` can be wider than `int`, thus it is possible for the difference to exceed `INT_MAX` and be well behaved.  Much like subtracting 2 `int` can yield a difference exceeding `int`, so can subtracting 2 pointers exceed `ptrdiff_t` for platforms that employ a narrow enough `ptrdiff_t` for its memory model.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Re: "size_t is wide enough to index any array": sounds like a good question to post should the spec that `sizeof`, returning `size_t` returning the size of objects, including arrays, not lend itself to sufficient support.

Answer (score -3):

This sounds like a problem with unsigned integer subtraction: If you subtract the "higher" pointer from the "lower", you'll get a negative difference. If you represent a negative number as an unsigned number, it will look like a very big number...

Comment: In my defense: I think the 2nd sentence "If so how could I access the elements of such an array that are beyond INT_MAX?" wasn't there when I answered. If you still think this answer is incorrect for the broader question, I'd be interested to know how / why?